# How to capture the response from go run main.go

Tags: shell, go

I have go script main.go which I am calling it from shell script. main.go returns the response as below on success. I am looking to capture the return response in a variable from the same shell script I am calling main.go

> Response from running go run main.go

```
  No content to read in :/labs/text/11/004/11-004_M0_1_arm_1.d78d350eef91f1e72d801e064a088cf80d3c840a-0023.txt


2023/07/13 04:46:52 /app/lab-processor/src/main.go:201 SLOW SQL >= 200ms
[1267.568ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM "pipeline1_2"."p_doc_pp_dates" WHERE filename LIKE '%11-004_M0_1_arm_1.d78d350eef91f1e72d801e064a088cf80d3c840a%' AND pagenumber = 38 ORDER BY begin desc LIMIT 1
```

First response is when ran first file where there is no content to read and second response in when there is something in the file and it loaded in the table

> I have tried something like

```
go run main.go > return_resp
echo $return_resp
```

however it was not much of help

Comment: It's unclear from your description, what exactly you consider a response. Is it the standard output of a program? Or the standard error? Or both?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `> return_resp` creates a file with that name, and you (vainly) try to echo a env variable with the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try these

```
return_resp=$(go run main.go)
echo $return_resp
```

or

```
go run main.go > output.txt 2>&1
cat output.txt
```

- [What does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/what-does-21-mean)

Comment: @shayam, just to emphasize this answer: with `my_command > response_resp` you have created the **file** `response_resp`, not a variable.